# Problem in navigation props in the bottomTabNavigator

Tags: navigation, react-native, tabnavigator

I am using this

```
 <View style={{flex:1}}>
                {this.state.screenSwitch ? (
                   <Screen1/>
                    ) : <Screen2/>}
                    </View>
```

in the return. As i am using this to interchange two screens in the single tabs in the Bottom tab Navigator, i am using

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen3')}>
```

But getting an error like this

undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.props.navigation.navigate')

So what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a function for handling navigation and call that onPress as given below

```
import {NavigationActions} from 'react-navigation'; 

constructor(props) {
   super(props);
}

navigateToScreen = (route) => () => {
    const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName: route
    });
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
}


render() {
    ...
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.navigateToScreen('Screen3')} ></TouchableOpacity>
    ...
}
```

Comment: Not working any of the above..@Ajith in your code i am not getting any output no  error.

Comment: Make sure that you have included props in your constructor, I have edited my answer, It works for me . I hope it should work for you as well

Answer (score 0):

this could happen due to `this` variable. Try to create a new variable called `self` and place it before the class declaration and follow this:

```
... //imports below
import ....

//here put new variable self
let self;
// your class here
export default class YourClass extends Component {
.....
    constructor() {
        //your constructor fooes...
        self = this;
    }
.....
// and then use self instead of this in your code.

....
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> self.props.navigation.navigate('Screen3')}>
....
```